# Not able to execute if condition in Cygwin terminal

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Am new to unix,While executing below shell, am getting error as "unexpected token `fi'". am not sure why this error encounter though syntax are correct.
can any one help on this?

code:

```
#!bin/bash -xv
echo "this is test"
a=10
echo $a
if [a -gt 5]
than 
echo "print"
echo $a+10
fi
```

O/P:

```
$ sh newsh.sh
this is test
10
newsh.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
newsh.sh: line 9: `fi'
```

Comment: Typo: `than` should be `then`

Comment: Use `[ $a -gt 5 ]` and do validate your code on shellcheck.net

Comment: Thank you very much Anubhava. shell check.net is really use full for me

Answer (score 1):

The shell tokenization is white-space sensitive. You must use

```
if [ $a -gt 5 ]; then
   do_something
   echo $((a + 10))
fi
```

And it's `#!/bin/sh`; count your slashes...

Comment: Thank you Jens, will verify my syntax